# How to append text from one txt file to multiple txt files and its sub directories .bat

Tags: cmd, merge, append

I have one .txt file with some text that I want to append to all .txt files in a folder and its sub directories

Can anyone explain to me how to do it?

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

rename the file which should be appended to append_me (or anything without .txt extension), then you can use a FOR loop over *.txt files in a batch file

```
@echo off
for /R "C:\MY_FOLDER\SUB_DIRECTORY" %%a in (*.txt) do type append_me >> %%a
```

Comment: you should `...  >> "%%a"` in case the text file names contain any problematic characters (like spaces)